# Terminal Server Client Licenses

Tags: sql-server, terminal-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

We have a new software project coming in and I need some advice for client licenses. (The people who are running the software are terribly hard to get answers out of).

The software runs on a Terminal Server with SQL Server as well - which we have already in our environment.

Then there are client machines that need: "Windows Terminal server client license" and "Microsoft SQL Server 2000 client license". What are these client licenses that are required?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client licenses are just what they sound like. They are licenses that entitle a user/computer to access the service (SQL or TS). For each seat that is directly accessing each service, you will need a CAL.

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx